# Assigning list items with for loop causing infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, counter, infinite-loop

I have a file with all zip codes in the US with their latitude and longitude. The file is in the format `ZIP,LAT, LONG\n`.

I plan on saving these to a database, so I have looped through the file word by word and set a `counter` variable. If the `counter == 1` it should assign the value to `zip_codes[]` if `counter == 2` assign the value to `latitude[]` and if `counter == 3` assign the value to `longitude[]`, but when I run the following code to test if it properly added the zip code values it becomes an infinite loop and I have to force quit IDLE

(file can be viewed at [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erichurst/7882666/raw/5bdc46db47d9515269ab12ed6fb2850377fd869e/US%2520Zip%2520Codes%2520from%25202013%2520Government%2520Data))

```
zip_code_file = open('zip_codes.txt')
zip_codes=[]
latitude=[]
longitude = []
counter = 1
for s in zip_code_file.read().split(','):
    s = s.strip()
    if counter ==1: 
        zip_codes.append(s)
        counter = counter +1
    elif counter == 2:
        latitude.append(s)
        counter = counter+1
    elif counter == 3:
        longitude.append(s)
        counter = 1
print(zip_codes)
```

anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
At the very least, we need enough input data to reproduce the problem.  Make it easy on us: replace `zip_code_file.read()` with hard-coded data.

Comment: ive updated it to include the link to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a little less loop:

```
zip_code_file = open('zip_codes.txt')
zip_codes = []
latitude = []
longitude = []
for line in zip_code_file:
    zipcode, lat, lng = line.strip().split(',')
    zip_codes.append(zipcode)
    latitude.append(lat)
    longitude.append(lng)
print(zip_codes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Files of comma separated values should be processed with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module

```
import csv

with open('zip_codes.txt') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r)  # skip the header
    zip_codes, latitudes, longitudes = zip(*r)
```